# Auto-building a native install AIR app

Tags: automation, air

I'm developing an AIR application that will be run on both OSX and Windows (it's part of an internal tool chain).  Part of the functionality of the application requires shelling out to external processes, so I've created a native installer package to get access to `NativeProcess`.  The app also needs to automatically update when a new version is available, so I've used the `NativeApplicationUpdater` library.

I'd like to set up automated builds of the app.  Unfortunately, it looks like building a native installer for a particular OS requires you to build it on that OS, making automated builds of both OSX and Windows versions impossible (at least on the same build machine).

If I could set up automated builds of a .air file, and then use that to update the native install, that would fit my workflow perfectly.  My question is: is that possible?  If not, are there any alternatives when it comes to auto-building a native install app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a native installer from the .air file:

```
adt -package 
  -target EXE or DMG
  NATIVE_SIGNING_OPTIONS (windows only and optional)
  output 
  input_package
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html